# Save the result of a function on a variable ocaml

Tags: list, function, variables, char, ocaml

I want to save the result of a function in a variable (Ocaml).
I have the function "let rec scorritutto lista1 lista2 temp" that take 2 char list list (list1 and list2) and a char list (temp), and give in output a char list.

```
let rec scorritutto lista1 lista2 best_temp = match lista1 with
    [] -> best_temp
  |hd::tl -> scorritutto (List.tl(lista1)) lista2 (migliorsott (List.hd(lista1)) lista2 best_temp)
;;
```

i want to save the result (char list) in a variable.

```
......
let best = scorritutto lista11 lista22 temp in
......
```

In this way i obtain a char list -> char list

how can i do for obtain a char list?

Comment: what is the signature of scorritutto function ?

Comment: val scorritutto : char list list -> char list list -> char list -> char list =
  <fun>

Comment: strange that you still get a function for best. you should be getting a char list. could you please also provide migliorsott code as well ?

Comment: 'let rec migliorsott lista1 lista2 best_temp= match lista2 with
[] -> best_temp
|hd::tl->
if List.length(sotcomune (lista1) (List.hd(lista2))) > List.length(best_temp) then
let best_temp = sotcomune lista1 (List.hd(lista2)) in
migliorsott lista1 (List.tl(lista2)) best_temp
else
migliorsott lista1 (List.tl(lista2)) best_temp
;;' thank you for your collaboration

Comment: val migliorsott : char list -> char list list -> char list -> char list =
  <fun>

Comment: there are a lot of other nested function

Comment: hmmm... it does not help as I expected :( - I just wanted to make sure of the signature of scorritutto by compiling it. When typing 'let best = scorritutto lista11 lista22 temp;;' in ocaml, you get a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not answer yet to your issue.

Here is what I did : I fake migliorsott the following way :

> let migliorsott (a : char list) (b : char list list) (c : char list) = c;;

so that I cut any dependencies to other functions and I can compile scorritutto with the right signature (the one you quote above).

```
let lista11 = [['a'];[]];;
let lista22 = [['b'];[]];;
let temp = ['c'];;
let best = scorritutto lista11 lista22 temp;;
```

returns : *** val best : char list = ['c'] ***

So, I get `best` as being a `char list` as you expect.

Comment: man, i don't know why, but i have just restarted my Ocaml IDE for answer to your questions, and now all work great....anyway thank you for your time